# Is $Log \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$ continous for $|z| < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that for $|z| < 1: \; \; Re(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}) > 0$, so the values in $Log$ are taken from numbers with positive real part.

I know that $0$ in denominator would appear only for $z = - i$ and it's outside of the circle.

Is that enaugh for $Log \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$ to be continous on $|z| < 1$?

Comment: The composition of two continuous functions is ... ?

Comment: Continuous, but I was not sure how does it work in complex space - because imaginary part of number $z$ that I put into $Log$ can be $<0$,

Comment: $z \mapsto \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$ maps the unit disk to the right halfplane (and is continuous), and $w \mapsto \operatorname{Log}(w)$ is continuous (even analytic) in the right halfplane. So the composition of these two functions is continuous. That is all you need to get your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\L}{\operatorname{Log}}$Let me write "$\L$" for the principal logarithm.

A composition $\L(f)$ is continuous on some domain $D$ iff. $f$ is continuous and $f$'s image on $D$ avoids the cut $(-\infty,0]$ (because then $f=\exp(\L(f))$ will be continuous, and in the other direction, $\L$ is continuously defined on $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$).

$z\mapsto\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$ is continuous on $\Bbb C\setminus\{i\}$. Does it avoid the cut? $\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\in(-\infty,0]$ if and only if its real part is nonpositive, and its imaginary part is zero. Let's check; write $z=x+iy$ for $x,y$ real.

$$\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\frac{1-y+ix}{1+y-ix}=\frac{(1-y^2-x^2)+i(2x)}{(1+y)^2+x^2}$$So it must be that $x=0$ and $1-y^2-0^2=1-y^2\le0$, that is, $1\le y^2$ and $z\in i\cdot\{(-\infty,-1]\sqcup[1,\infty)\}$.

On the domain $D=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\}$, it follows that $z\mapsto\L\left(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\right)$ is indeed continuous. This is true on a much larger domain, in fact, the complement: $$\Bbb C\setminus\{(-i\infty,-i]\sqcup[i,i\infty)\}$$